# Calling unknown method: frontend\models\ContactForm::save()

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
 public function addContact()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }

    $model = new ContactForm();

    foreach (['name', 'email', 'subject', 'body'] as $property) {
        $model->$property = $this->$property;
    }
    return $model->save();
}
```

I get this error:

> Calling unknown method: frontend\models\ContactForm::save()

the var_dump is working properly.
[image: vardump]

the save method return this error [save method [image: savemethod2].

This is the complete model rules :
[rules model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIhxQ.png)
and this is the rest of the model code : 
[rest of model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Ktm.png)
Could someone tell me what I'm getting wrong?

Comment: Do you have method save on ContactForm Model? How do you create this Model? Do you use ActiveRecords?

Comment: save is a predefined method in yii2 framework

Comment: I know but the error you get is clear, please share your model

Comment: ok I edited the post

Comment: Your model extends Model and If i remember method save() is not a method of Model class. For example save() is a method of [ActiveRecords Model](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activerecord)

Comment: I know and  I have tried all uses traits in this page

Comment: For Example if you don't extend ActiveRecords you have to write your own save method

Comment: I add Activerecord to the extends and the error don't display again but the data doesn't save in the database

Comment: if doesnt'save try to var_dump $model->getErrors();

Comment: it return an empty array

Comment: How do you get the data? I think you have some logic errors, i'llsuggest to read how ActiveRecords works with View, Controller and Models. [https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record)

Comment: when I use var_dump it return all the values properly I think I get all the data correctly

Comment: Your verify code is null, are you sure that is correct according to your rules?

Comment: I don't need to save it in the database

Comment: So you have to set as safe, probably you have some validation error

Comment: I dont think that because the page contact is generated automaically when I create the project

Answer (score 0):

As Sfili_81 already mentioned you have to extend ActiveRecord instead of Model to be able call the save method. But that only makes sense if you want to save the data to a database.

You can use the default logic of the yii2-app-basic to send the data submitted via ContactForm to a configured admin via email. To do so you just have to call the contact method of ContactForm.

```
// SiteController::actionContact

$model = new ContactForm();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->contact(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])) {
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('contactFormSubmitted');
    return $this->refresh();
}
```

If you want to receive real emails you also have to set the `useFileTransport` property of the mailer component to false (in config/web.php), otherwise every mail gets saved to runtime/mail.

Comment: My controller code is almost like this. the send of the email is works properly I just want to save the data in database